# The transaction has been cancelled, but our business server can still receive the webhook with successful payment

Tags: django, paypal

[This is one of the customers who failed to pay and cancelled the Recurring payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nppr.png)

However, my business server receives a Payment sale completed Webhook notification set up on paypal, I'm very confused

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the cancellation happens after the payment is completed, you will also receive webhooks for payment cancellations. Subscribe to such events if you haven't.

Comment: However, the Payment sale completed webhook is triggered after the Payment is successfully completed. If it is cancelled, why will the webhook be triggered

Comment: Step 1 payment completes. Step 2 payment completion webhook is sent. Step 3 payment is cancelled. Step 4 cancellation webhook will be sent. I don't know what the event name is, but you can subscribe to all webhooks with `*` to ensure you receive it.

Comment: Notification emails are also often sent for these events, if you want to look at the timeline there.